# Howto change the default radius logging path for accounting?

Tags: freeradius, accounting

I have freeradius 2.1.12+dfsg-1.2 working and logging accounting packets to `/var/log/freeradius/radacct/detail-20130401`.

However I need to `tail` the log and I want to ideally tail a single log file and manage the logs with logrotate.

What do I change to make it log to just `/var/log/freeradius/radacct/detail` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v2.x.x/raddb/modules/detail#L34

Change the value of the detailfile config item.

Comment: Thanks Arran. Could you also please take a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/495068/how-to-allow-any-ip-to-log-to-radius-accounting ?